# Role based element population in angular application

Tags: angular, security

I am working on a project where my UI components are tightly coupled to the login user role/permissions. (I am using angular 4 for front end and spring at backend)

On successful login of user backend server returns user object along with his permissions. according to those permissions I need to render the various components on UI.

Demo User Object looks like:

```
{
    "empId": "1",
    "username": "prasad.parab@u.com",
    "Permissions": [
        "viewOwnLeaveData",
        "viewOwnWorkData",
        "viewTeamLeaveData",
        "viewOrgLeaveData",
        "viewOrgWorkData"
    ],
    "password": "*****************",
    "accountNonLocked": true,
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true
}
```

**scenario 1** : if logged in user have 2 permissions(viewOwnLeaveData, viewOwnWorkData) I want to render two charts describing his leaveData and workData on dashboard.

**scenario 2** : if logged in user have 4 permissions(viewOwnLeaveData, viewOwnWorkData, viewTeamLeaveData, viewTeamWorkData) then I want to render 4 charts on dashboard etc.

when user click on any chart the further options also depend on the permissions.(i.e. if user have updateOwnLeaveData permission then it should see edit button)

Currently I am doing this in single component(DashBoardComponent), in this i am added multiple if else like

```
if (user.permissions.indexOf(viewOwnLeaveData) != -1) {
// code to create and populate own leave data chart
}

if (user.permissions.indexOf(viewTeamLeaveData) != -1) {
// code to create and populate team leave data chart
}
.
.
.
```

In this design I face two problems

1. As all logic written in single component, with increase list of     permissions the if blocks is increasing and code becomes very bulky.
2. When I click on any component the next element is loaded on UI(e.g. click on myLeaveData chart populates list of leave records below the chart) and if I press back button it redirects me to login page (Expected to hide list of leave records)

Any way to doing this in better and modular way?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Whole logic in single component will make your application tightly coupled and not scallable. You need to create component for each permission related features.

At Runtime, you can show or hide using *ngIf (or) you can dynamically render the component using view container Ref.

Comment: So did yo mean import another component into dashboard component?

if yes then what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Might be, you can maintain shared module with those components declared and exported. By importing the shared module to dashboard module. You can use those exported components.